# Scaning specified area for random curve and get coordinates

Tags: matlab, coordinates

I want to scan the curve in matlab for a specified area suppose 0-10 in X axis and 50-150 in y-axis and get the co-ordinates of the points of the line.

I am very new in this. I am starting from scratch. so any help is appreciated.

regards 
Borad

[image]

Comment: How is your line created/plotted?

Comment: Is it a picture or a plotted matrix?

Comment: its a random line created... on paint.